# Getting data from a model using an ObjectController from within the template in Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember-cli

I am trying to get a single model to load into my ObjectController and I am having a hard time getting it to show up in my template. My other routes use an ArrayController so when I'm in the template I just do the following to iterate over each object:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    ..
    {{item.firstName}}
    ..
{{/each}}
```

But I cannot figure out how to do that if there aren't more than a single item in the model. Looking at the following link: [Ember.js Docs on ObjectController](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/) it should be incredibly easy but mine doesn't seem to be working properly. Below is the stubbed out code that I'm using. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

app/router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
});

Router.map(function() {

    this.route('login', {path: '/'}, function(){
        this.resource('login');
    });

    this.route('items', {path: '/items'}, function(){
        this.resource('items');
    });

    this.route('item-details', {path: '/item/:item_id'}, function(){
        this.resource('item-details');
    });

});
export default Router;
```

app/routes/item-details.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('item-details');
    }
});
```

app/models/item-details.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var ItemDetails = DS.Model.extend({
    itemNumber: DS.attr('string')
});

ItemDetails.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, itemNumber: '0000001'}
    ]
});

export default ItemDetails;
```

app/controllers/item-details.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
```

app/templates/item-details.hbs:

```
Item Number: {{itemNumber}}<br/>
{{model}}<br/>
{{model.itemNumber}}<br/>
{{model.data.itemNumber}}<br/>
{{content.itemNumber}}<br/>
{{model.content.0.itemNumber}}<br/>
```

The displayed value of the template when I run the above is:

```
Item Number: 
<DS.RecordArray:ember377>
<three blanks>
0000001
```

I have also verified that the DS does get created. I can view it in the Ember debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine figured it out, here's what we did:

app/routes/item-details.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('item-details', params.item_id);
    }
});
```

app/models/item-details.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var ItemDetails = DS.Model.extend({
    itemNumber: DS.attr('string')
});

ItemDetails.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: '0000001', itemNumber: '0000001'}
    ]
});

export default ItemDetails;
```

The problem, it seems, is that it was still returning an array of items since it was potentially receiving more than one item from the datastore using the .find() notation originally?

Either way with the changes above the following template worked and displayed appropriately:

```
Item Number: {{itemNumber}}
```